# Best practice to maintain minified files and deployment/development

Tags: javascript, css, deployment, minify

I'm stuck in a bit of dilemma on how to get around this and was hoping someone would point me in the right direction.

I am trying to cut down on the size of css and javascript files to improve our website's performance. But the problem is, on deployment, we simply upload our current svn repository's latest development version onto the server.

I am finding it hard to add that extra step for every developer to minify files before every change, as it adds a risk for negligence and human error.

I was thinking about having the readable version of files on the server anyway, but having some kind of file monitor that will execute a minifier when a file is changed, and update the file used by the website. Has anyone implemented this before?

**EDIT**

We're currently running on ASP.Net 2.0, Windows Server 2003

Comment: What platforms and language(s) are you using on server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .net on the server, you could also try [RequestReduce](http://RequestReduce.com) available on Nuget. It minies and bundles your css and js and also sprites css background images. It does it on the fly so your devs don't have to do this as an extra step. As long as you have some kind of versioning in place that changes the css/js url when it is changed, RequestReduce will automatically detect the change and process the file. It does all of this in the background and there fore does not affect the response time. If the files are not versioned via the url, RequestProduce provides a dashboard where you can flush its cache. RequestReduce can be deployed with absolutely no code changes and hardly any config in most use cases.

Comment: Has to be installed on Visual Studio though doesn't it?

All our developers will upload changes from time to time, meaning Nuget will have to be installed everywhere. I'm trying to find a solution that can be applied on our webserver.

Comment: Apolgies matt, I found that it was quite easy to add to a project without using Nugent, so I went on using it, but I'm having trouble on  the webserver as I have caching and compression switched on, any ideas?

Comment: Should work with compression and usually caching too. There are some things to be aware of. Look at https://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce/wiki/RequestReduce-is-not-working.-I-don%27t-see-any-spriting-or-minification.-How-can-I-troubleshoot-this%3F for help and also open an issue on the github site (https://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce/issues) and I can work with you.

Comment: @MattWrock, regarding the part about "some kind of versioning in place", is it true that RequestReduce does not currently have the ability detect file changes and invalidate its cache based on that? File changes are the optimal time for cache busting in both development and production environments, but it's not trivial to implement and unfortunately could be a dealbreaker for me. Are you planning on adding file change monitoring at some point? I hope so, I love this tool otherwise!

Comment: Yes. That is on the road map. I'm weighing that vs. Foreground spriting as the new "big" feature to add. Leaning toward the refreshing. What I also plan is to check external files for changes as well. Currently RequestReduce does not crunch scripts that include a "near future" expiration and this would allow it to process alot more scripts like possibly social widgets.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET, try [MBCompression library](http://mbcompression.codeplex.com/) - it minify files automatically and you don't need do it manually: